# C++ - Cloning into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, push, clone

So `push_back` only adds a copy of an object into a vector of my class `std::vector<Action*>`. I have a `clone` method on objects that I'm pushing into a vector: `stack.push_back(pattern->actions[a]->clone());` where clone is returning a new object with all of the same properties. Is this pointless? Does `push_back` do what I want it to do already?

Comment: How is your `vector` instance declared?  `std::vector<foo>` or `std::vector<foo *>`, or ...?

Comment: Your vector doesn't hold objects, just pointers. So it cannot hold copies of an object.

Comment: Maybe use a smart-pointer like [copy_ptr](http://axter.com/smartptr/classcopy__ptr.htm) my google-fu just conjured up?

Comment: @Deduplicator rather `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` than home-brewed implementations

Comment: @Erbureth: But OP wants it copied, and neither `shared_ptr` nor `unique_ptr` do that.

Comment: @Deduplicator That is the job for copy-constructor or the clone method

Comment: @Erbureth: So, you want to go the fully manual way? You know that code is all home-brewed?

Comment: _Does push_back do what I want it to do already?_ - What _do_ you want to do? The question as it is now is utterly unclear. Are the pointers in the vector supposed to hold ownership? Do you want to share ownership between pointers or create a new clone for each entry? Are you fine with an explicit call to `clone` for each copy or do you want that to be wrapped away for you?

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` stores a cpy of it's argument. But the argument is a *pointer*, not the *pointee*.

Because you say that `Action` is a polymorphic type, we cannot do the natural thing and just use a `std::vector<Action>` instead.

Consider your requirements, and then choose another solution. Here some for you:

1. Use non-owning raw pointers and don't clone if you are ok with just referring to that object, and it will live long enough.
2. Eschew high-level constructs and do your cloning manually as you showed.
3. Consider [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html). Still, you must know all derived classes when you define it.
4. Use `std::unique_ptr` if the vector shall own the `Action` (Also see `std::make_unique`).
5. Use `std::shared_ptr` if it should share ownership (Also see `std::make_shared`).
6. Use `std::weak_ptr` if the vector does not own and shall not keep alive the `Action`.
7. Use a home-brew [`copy_ptr` like this](http://axter.com/smartptr/classcopy__ptr.htm) for automatic cloning.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<Action*>` stores pointers to `Action`s.

> So push_back only adds a copy of an object into a std::vector.

It is more accurate to state that it adds a copy of a pointer to an `Action`.  For the most part, no, this premise is wrong.

> ... `stack.push_back(pattern->actions[a]->clone());` where `clone` is returning a new object with all of the same properties. Is this pointless?

No, it's not pointless.  But it's contrary to the idiom.  You should consider instead creating a copy constructor, using `std::vector<Action>` (and heed the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)!).

Comment: Unless `Action` is a polymorphic type and `clone()` returns a pointer to one of its derived types.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes there are several subclasses of Action